# Enable/Disable checkboxes along with form submit on dropdownlist on change event in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've submitted the form using dropdownlist onchange method using jQuery which works fine. Also I wanted to enable the checkboxes along with the form submission using the same dropdownlist onchange event when the value is selected.

My Form is,

```
{!! Form::open( array('route' => array('main.customerequipment.search',$customer_id), 'id'=>'equipment_form', 'name'=>'equipment_form', 'data-toggle'=>"validator") ) !!}

    {!! Form::select('filter_by', @$owner_name,'', array('id'=>'filter_by', 'placeholder'=>trans('main.all'), 'class' => 'form-control')) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Below is my code:

```
$("#filter_by").on("change", function () {
    localStorage.realOwnerFilter = $('select[name^="filter_by"] option:selected').val();
    $("#equipment_form").submit();
    if($(this).val() == '')
    { 
        $("#download_certificate").attr('disabled','disabled');
        $(".select_all").attr('disabled','disabled');
        $(".select_particular").attr('disabled','disabled');
        $(".select_all").prop('checked',false);
        $(".select_particular").prop('checked',false);
    }   
    else
    {
        $(".select_all").removeAttr("disabled");
        $(".select_particular").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

**Note:** Enable/disable the checkboxes works fine when i exclude the below line,

```
$("#equipment_form").submit();
```

And when I include that particular line my checkboxes does not work properly. I think the problem is with the form submission for which I'm not so sure.

Comment: Have you tried this line '$("#equipment_form").submit();' after the if-else block ?

Comment: Yup.. But got the same prob.. :(

Comment: try this one `$("#equipment_form").unbind().submit();`. If it works then the form have another event bound to it.

Comment: I tried with your code. same prob occurring..

Comment: Can u add u r form details in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Add `onSubmit` in your form:

```
<form id="equipment_form" onSubmit="mySubmit(event)">
```

Your dropdownlist onChange will be:

```
$("#filter_by").on("change", function () {
localStorage.realOwnerFilter = $('select[name^="filter_by"] option:selected').val();
$("#equipment_form").submit();
}
```

And mySubmit function will be:

```
function mySubmit(event) {
if ($("#filter_by").val() == '') {
    $("#download_certificate").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $(".select_all").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $(".select_particular").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $(".select_all").prop('checked', false);
    $(".select_particular").prop('checked', false);
} else {
    $(".select_all").removeAttr("disabled");
    $(".select_particular").removeAttr("disabled");
}
event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: When I use your code it stated the following error, "Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined"

Comment: after adding event it enables the checkboxes but form submission is not taken place. I think it might be we used preventDefault(). What do you say?

Comment: yes, preventDefault() will stop the form submission.

Comment: but I want both enabling checkboxes and form submit at a time, when the dropdown list have selected value

Comment: It might be overkill, but you can use cookie for that. On form submit, set a cookie and on $(document).ready() check the cookie value, disable/enable check boxes and reset the cookie value.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the above issue by using my own code given below:

I just wrote the below lines inside the document.ready(function()),

```
document.ready(function(){        
    var real_owner = localStorage.realOwnerFilter;
    if(real_owner =='' || real_owner == undefined )
    {
        $(".checkboxToggle").hide();
        $(".realOwner").hide();
        $(".select_particular").hide();
        $("#download_certificate").attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
    else 
    {
        $(".checkboxToggle").show();
        $(".realOwner").show();
        $(".select_particular").show();
    } 
});

$("#filter_by").on("change", function () {
    localStorage.realOwnerFilter = $('select[name^="filter_by"] option:selected').val();
    $("#equipment_form").submit();
});
```